# ServletContext().getRealPath("") returns path not ending with /

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have been using this "ServletContext.getRealPath("")" till Tomcat8 and I got the return string path ending with a slash.

```
For Example ServletContext.getRealPath("")+"resources" will return /home/company/eclipse_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Project_Title/resources
```

But when I tried with Tomcat 9.0 I got path without a slash

```
For Example ServletContext.getRealPath("")+"resources" will return /home/company/eclipse_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/Project_Titleresources
```

Slash after 'Project_Title' is missing. This exception only occurs after deployment(.WAR). There is no issue in local.

Hope somebody can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: You can avoid all that by *not* concatenating path strings, and instead using `Path.get(base, extension)`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How to get 'base'?

Comment: It isnt 'missing'. It isn't supposed to be there. What you get is a valid directory name. *Not* a URL. You can use it to compose filenames in the ordinary way.

Comment: @SuhailMoideen, you should follow WebResources API and use paths that start with "/", as it expects. See [ServletContext::getContextPath](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()).

Comment: `ServletContext.getRealPath("")+"resources"` could have been written as `new File(ServletContext.getRealPath(""), "resources")`, but really you should have written it far more simply as `ServletContext.getRealPath("resources")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed the issue.

The issue was, I didn't put '/' before "resources".

```
ServletContext.getRealPath("")+"/resources"
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to pass web-inf in to getrealpath().if you pass nothing the it will return you full absolut path of you project.

`application=getServletContext();
application.getRealPath("WEB-INF"); //retrun null
application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF"); //RETRUN absolute`ServletContext `

Comment: How can you possibly know magically where his 'resources' directory is in his Webapp?